# Go into main screen directly

Tags: lock-screens

Good day!

ColorOS version V6.1.2,
Android version 9

The problem I am facing is: when the screen on, it shows a cover page, I need to swipe up once, then it enters the main screen. (there's no password setup for the screen on.)

How can I make it goes into the main screen, once the power button is on (without any screen protector or cover etc)?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like on your device is "Swipe to unlock" activated. I am not familiar with ColorOS - on regular Android devices you could change this in Android Settings -> Security -> Screen lock.

Comment: @Robert, thank you for the comment. But seems it's different and there's no "Screen lock" in Security...